# simple chemistry formula formating

Tags: python

given a chemical formula such as Al2(SO4)3 i want to format it by looking where the brackets are and multiplying the 3 at the end by the SO4 in brackets giving the output of Al2S3O12. I am getting a syntax error on line 40 and i suspect there are many more errors. I am looking as to what i might have done wrong and how I can improve this code. I am using repl as the ide if that helps. thanks in advance.

```
def format(equation):
  a = 0
  equation_list = []
  formated = ''

  for i in range (len(equation)):
    equation_list.append(equation[i])


  for i in range(a,len(equation)):
    if equation[i] == '(':
      opening = equation[i]
    elif equation[i] == ')':
      closing = equation[i]
      a = closing
      multiplier = closing+1 
      break

  


    for i in range(len(equation_list[opening:closing+1])):

      if equation_list[i].isupper():

        if equation_list[i+1].islower():

          if equation_list[i+2].islower():
            equation_list.insert(i+3, str(multiplier))
          elif equation_list[i+2].isupper():
            equation_list.insert(i+3, str(multiplier))
          elif equation_list[i+2].isdigit():
            equation_list[i+3] *=multiplier

        
        elif equation_list[i+1].isupper():

          equation_list.insert(i+1, str(multiplier)

        elif equation_list[i+1].isdigit():

          equation_list[i+1] *= multiplier

  equation_list.remove('(')
  equation_list.remove(')')
  for i in equation_list:
    formated += equation_list[i]

  return formated





print(format('Na(Cl)2'))
```

Comment: `equation_list.insert(i+1, str(multiplier)` is missing a parenthesis and `opening` and `closing` aren't always defined. In addition, your indentation is completely wrong - the second for-loop is inside the first one.

Comment: This is basically an expression evaluator.  The code you have would only handle one-digit multipliers, and would not handle nested parentheses.  The general case solution is a bit wordy, but it will handle arbitrary formulae.  I'll post it below as an example.

Answer (score 0):

This will handle nested brackets and double-digit multipliers.  It will not combine separated atoms in like '(CH2OH)3', but that can be an exercise.

```
def format(equation):
    parts = []
    partial = 0
    for char in equation+' ':
        if char.isnumeric():
            partial = partial * 10 + int(char)
            continue

        if partial:
            if parts[-1] == ')':
                parts.pop()
                i = -1
                while parts[i] != '(':
                    parts[i][1] *= partial
                    i -= 1
            else:
                parts[-1][1] = partial
            partial = 0

        if char.isupper():
            parts.append( [char, 1] )
        elif char.islower():
            parts[-1][0] += char
        elif char == '(':
            parts.append('(')
        elif char == ')':
            parts.append(')')
    build = []
    for part in parts:
        print(part)
        if part == '(':
            continue
        if part[1] == 1:
            build.append( part[0] )
        else:
            build.append( part[0] + str(part[1]))
    return ''.join(build)

print(format('Al2(SO4)3'))
print(format('Al2((SO4)3)10'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest using `re` (regex module) for this problem. the code I  came up with is:

```
import re
def format(equation):
    parantheses_regex = "\((?P<inner_equation>[A-Za-z\d]+)\)(?P<multipli_number>\d+)"
    get_inner_values = "(?P<symb>[A-Z]([a-z])?)(?P<number>\d+)?"
    search_parantheses = re.finditer(parantheses_regex, equation)
    for value in search_parantheses:
        multipli = value.group("multipli_number")
        inner_equation = value.group("inner_equation")
        search_equation = re.finditer(get_inner_values, inner_equation)
        new_inner = ""
        for inner_symb in search_equation:
            number  = inner_symb.group("number") 
            symb = inner_symb.group("symb")
            if number == None:
                number = 1
            number = int(number)
            new_inner += symb + str(number * int(multipli))
        equation = re.sub("\(" + value.group(1) + "\)(?P<multipli_number>\d+)", new_inner, equation)
    return equation


print(format("Al2(SO4)3"))
```

**Output:**

```
Al2S3O12
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a parser that does the job. It handles nested parentheses as well. It assumes that the string passed is correct:

```
class El:
    def __init__(self, name, number = 1):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.number == 1:
            return self.name
        else:
            return self.name + str(self.number)
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if self.number == 1:
            return self.name
        else:
            return self.name + str(self.number)

# CARE: this implementation wants a well formatted string
import re
def parseRegular(a: str):
    r = re.split(r'(\(|\)|[A-Z][a-z]?[0-9]*)', a)
    result = []
    for i in r:
        if i == '':
            pass
        elif i == '(' or i == ')' or i.isdigit():
            result.append(i)
        else:
            # parse element
            pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<name>[A-Z]([a-z]?))(?P<number>[0-9]*)')
            match = pattern.match(i)
            # Not checking for exception here (if no match -> NoneType). Also not checking for invalid input.
            number = match.group('number')
            name = match.group('name')
            if number != "":
                result.append(El(name, int(number)))
            else:
                result.append(El(name))
    return result

def multiplyParsed(a):
    n = len(a) - 1
    local = [*a]
    multFactors = []
    curr = 1
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        if str(a[i]).isdigit():  # a[i - 1] is == ')'
            curr = int(a[i])
            del local[i]
        elif a[i] == '(':
            del local[i]
            multFactors.pop()
        elif a[i] == ')':
            multFactors.append(curr)
            curr = 1
            del local[i]
            pass
        else:
            for m in multFactors:
                local[i].number *= m
    return local

formula = input()
elements = multiplyParsed(parseRegular(formula))
for i in elements:
    print(str(i), end="")
```

Examples:

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| Na(Cl)2 | NaCl2 |
| Al2(SO4)3 | Al2S3O12 |
| Al(Yh79O8(A10))4(Aj9) | AlYh316O32A40Aj9 |
| Au((A3B2)3(CD9)2)4AlB | AuA36B24C8D72AlB |

Notes: the function parseRegular can be simplified to better use regular expressions. The whole code could be improved to check for the correctness of the string.