# trying to make progrm to format chemical equation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given an input of something like `Na(Cl2)3Al(AlCl2)4` I am trying to make a program without any libraries to do this and the code that I made is not working and I cant figure out why.

can someone show me exactly where i am going wrong (or fix it for me)? the output for the example input should look like `NaCl6AlAl4Cl8` where brackets are removed also. thanks in advance for any help.

```
def format(equation):
  equation_list = list(equation)
  formated = ''

  
  for i in range(len(equation_list)): 
    if equation_list[i] == '(':
      opening = i
    if equation_list[i] == ')':
      closing = i
      
  
      for i in range(opening+1,closing):
        if equation_list[i].isdigit():
          equation_list[i] = str(int(equation_list[i])*mult)
        
        if equation_list[i].upper():
          if equation_list[i+1].isupper():
            equation_list[i+1] = str(mult)
          elif equation_list[i+1].isdigit():
            equation_list[i+1] = str(int(equation_list[i+1])*mult)
          else:
            if equation_list[i+2].isupper():
              equation_list[i+2] = str(mult)
            elif equation_list[i+2].isdigit():
              equation_list[i+2] = str(int(equation_list[i+2])*mult)
            else:
              if equation[i+3].isdigit():
                equation_list[i+3] = str(int(equation_list[i+3])*mult)
              else:
                equation[i+3] = str(mult)

        

  for i in equation_list:
    formated+=i


  return formated
print(format('Na(Cl2)3Al(AlCl2)4'))
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions, update or answer your previous one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187031/simple-chemistry-formula-formating

Answer (score 2):

As the [pointed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67187031) has no voted-up answered, I'd like to propose one, based on regexes. I'm pretty sure it doesn't match all cases, but yours at least

```
import re

EQ_PATTERN = re.compile(r"([A-Z][a-z]+\d*|\((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\d*)+\)\d*)")
BLOCK_PATTERN = re.compile(r"\(((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\d*)+)\)(\d*)")
ELEMENT_PATTERN = re.compile(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)(\d*)")

def format_element(element: str, amount: str, factor: int):
    return f"{element}{int(amount or '1') * factor}"

def format_block(block: str):
    if '(' not in block:
        return block
    inside, factor = BLOCK_PATTERN.findall(block)[0]
    return "".join(format_element(element, amount, int(factor))
                   for element, amount in ELEMENT_PATTERN.findall(inside))

def format_equation(eq: str):
    return "".join(map(format_block, EQ_PATTERN.findall(eq)))
```

With some tests

```
for eq in ('(Al3Cl2Ag6Au)4', 'Na(Cl2)3Al(AlCl2)4', 'Na2(Cl2)3Al(Al3Cl2)4'):
    print(f"{eq:20s} ==> {format_equation(eq)}")

(Al3Cl2Ag6Au)4       ==> Al12Cl8Ag24Au4
Na(Cl2)3Al(AlCl2)4   ==> NaCl6AlAl4Cl8
Na2(Cl2)3Al(Al3Cl2)4 ==> Na2Cl6AlAl12Cl8
```

Comment: I would have accepted the other answers but the only thing is I dont understand any of the code especially the ones using regex

Comment: @Mr.AwesomePants I just realised that you were the author of the duplicate .. you just asked the same on a new post ^^ if you don’t understand : learn about it :)